# All backgroundColor change by using *ngFor [ngStyle]

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is a typescript and html problem. Let me describe the situation.
There is a input box and a button. when I type in the input box it atomically shows the character by a paragraph which i typed in the input box. When I click the button a function    `onClickAllow()`    works. the function basically check a random value negative or positive. It also push the input text in the array. The output is: index_number.input_text with background color. When    `Math.Random() > .5`    the background color will be red otherwise green. My code also works. But the problem is when the color change it also change the previous content. [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nljfw.jpg) [typescript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCRde.jpg) [Output-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDmZ9.jpg) [Output-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VLX2.jpg)

If you see Output-1 shows the 1st element with red background color but in Output-2 when the 2nd element comes with green background color, it also change the 1st element background color. But I want separate element with separate background color.

Comment: Create a https://stackblitz.com/ so we can look into your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Component: typescript Templete: html*

```js
array = [];
status = '';

onClickButton(){
this.status = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'negative' : 'positive';
this.array.push({name: 'name', type: this.status});
}
```

```html
<button (click)="onClickButton()">Button</button>
<div *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
    <p [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: item.type == 'negative' ? 'red' : 'green'}">{{ i+1 }}.{{ item.name }}</p>
</div>
```

This solution is working.

Answer (score 1):

as far I understand you just want a color base of element position in the ngFor items list , this can be solve by get the index of each item and get color base of index.

*componnet*

```
  public getColor(index :number) : string {
    switch( index) { 
      case 0 : return "#f00"
      case 1 : return "#0f0"
      case 2 : return "#00f"
      default: return "#abc"
    }
  }
```

*template*

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of list;let i=index" [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor:getColor(i)}">
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jk4jv3)

**Updated**

a pipe will be a reusable solution

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'color'
})
export class ColorPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(index: number): any {
    switch( index) { 
      case 0 : return "#f00"
      case 1 : return "#0f0"
      case 2 : return "#00f"
      default: return "#abc"
    }
  }

}
```

*template*

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of list;let i=index" [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: i | color }">
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1e14be)

Comment: if the getColor(i) method is declared in the component itself, it gets difficult to reuse! Maybe a attribute directive is a good place, so we can use it across different components!

Comment: @Okyo I try to make the answer simple as posible but you are right here and I think a pipe will do a pretty job, I have update the anwer ,thanks for the feedback 

Comment: Nice solution! Angular is a masterpiece of frontend framework!

Comment: @Okyo  yes  one of the best

Comment: Thanks @malbarmawi .I tried by your getColor() method but it won't working. I didn't tried to your pipe method. so don't know that will be working or not. But I got a simplest solution. the solution is in the Answer section of the post. Thanks all

Comment: @Shatu happy that you found a solution